# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, stripe-payments

Making an eCommerce app with React. This is a "handleSubmit" function that is returning an error every time I'm trying to checkout.

I have imported "db" and declared "paymentIntent". It is still coming up with this error in the browser.

````
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        //do fancy stripe stuff
        event.preventDefault()
        setProcessing(true)

        // const payload = await stripe

        const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
            }
        }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
            //paymetnIntent = payment Confirmation

           db
            .collection('users') 
            .doc(user?.uid)
            .collection('orders')
            .doc(paymentIntent?.id)
            .set({
                basket: basket,
                amount: paymentIntent.amount,
                created: paymentIntent.created,
            })

            setSucceeded(true);
            setError(null)
            setProcessing(false)
            dispatch({
                type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
            })

            history.replace('/orders')
        })

    }```
````

Comment: Could you please add console.log(paymentIntent) after line in the beginning of the then body

Comment: @Tatiana It is resulting "undefined"

Comment: It means there is no paymentIntent. You should think about how to handle this case. Try to find out what you get from confirmCardPayment and why there is no paymentIntent

Comment: Should I console.log the "payload" or the  "confirmCardPayment" to get what is happening out there?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check if there are any `error`s. `.confirmPayment()` returns a promise and when it's resolved a [result object](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-options). It has two keys, `paymentIntent` (the one you already use), and `error` (the one you need to check):

```js
.then(({ error, paymentIntent }) => {
  // check if there is any error
  if (error || !paymentIntent) {
    // handle error, tell the user
    // ...
    // return to exit code
    return;
  }

  db.collection('users')
    .doc(user?.uid)
    .collection('orders')
    .doc(paymentIntent.id)
    .set({
      basket: basket,
      amount: paymentIntent.amount,
      created: paymentIntent.created,
    });

  setSucceeded(true);
  setError(null);
  setProcessing(false);
  dispatch({
    type: 'EMPTY_BASKET',
  });

  history.replace('/orders');
});
```

Comment: When I console logged the error, it is returning an object with client ID, ```payment_Intent``` , lats payment error, payment method types and etc.

Comment: Are you sure you've added the curly brackets like I did? `({ error, paymentIntent }) => {`

Comment: Yes, the code I shared contains the curly braces., Console logging the error is returning an undefined object.  What should I do with that? @Zsolt

Comment: Just to make sure that I can understand you correctly. Do both `error` and `paymentIntent` return undefined?

Comment: I am really sorry for the miscommunication earlier. The ```error``` returns an object, which is: 

```Object
message: "As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports"
param: "description"
payment_intent:
amount: 23900
canceled_at: null
cancellation_reason: null
capture_method: "automatic"
client_secret: "xxx"
confirmation_method: "automatic"
created: 1628091493
currency: "usd"
description: null
id: "xxx" ``` etc

and console logging ```paymentIntent``` is not returning anything on the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem some time ago and we have to notice that in the stipe documentation for [confirmCardPayment](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment), it says the returning result object is **either** the **payment intent** or the **error**.

So if the request is successful you'll receive a payment intent object for the response as,

```json
{
   "id": "xxx", 
   "amount": 30, 
   "created": 123213,
    ... 
}
```

or if the request fails the response would be an error as,

```json
{
   "error": {
      "code": "parameter_unknown",
      "message": "Error message",
      "payment_intent": {
          "id": "xxx",
          "amount": 30,
          ...
       }
   }
}
```

Note that in the success response you'll get the payment intent object itself so there will be no property as `paymentIntent` in the response object and that's why you get it as `undefined`. So in your code you'll have to do as,

```js
.then(({ id, amount, created, error }) => {
     if(error) {
        // error handling
        // dispatch error action
      } else {
        db.collection('users') 
         .doc(user?.uid)
         .collection('orders')
         .doc(id) // destructured id from paymentIntent object
         .set({
            basket: basket,
            amount, // destructured amount from paymentIntent object
            created, // destructured created from paymentIntent object
           })

         setSucceeded(true);
         setError(null)
         setProcessing(false)
         dispatch({
              type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
         })

         history.replace('/orders')
      }
})
```

Comment: I have destructured it using this
 ```db
            .collection('users') 
            .doc(user?.uid)
            .collection('orders')
            .doc(paymentIntent?.id)
            .set({
                basket: basket,
                amount: paymentIntent.amount,
                created: paymentIntent.created,
            })```

And still, it is returning an empty object, which consists of the amount, the client id everything, but somehow it is undefined.

Comment: An ```Object``` is something I am getting after console logging the ```error```, which consists of amount, client ID etc,
and console logging the ```paymentIntent``` is returning ```undefined```

Comment: @GouravSanyal Did you try destructuring the response as `.then({ id, amount, created, error })` ?  If the error exists, that means your request has failed. If that is the case, check for the `code` and the `message` of the error object and try to resolve it.

Comment: I made a small mistake earlier in the if-else block, your suggestion has worked. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Great to hear that @GouravSanyal. Appreciate it if you can mark the answer as correct then. :)

Comment: Sorry for miscommunicating the error. The ```Object``` I was getting was from the reducer. As I apply your method without passing in the ```paymentIntent``` , the whole app crashes and it is returning this error in the browser :

```Error: Payment(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.```

Can you please tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add console.log(paymentIntent) after line in the beginning of the then body and check the format it has. If it contains the **amount property** in paymentIntent then Add the **checks** before extracting the amount property as it **might** be taking sometime to load that. So,

```
       .set({
            basket: basket,
            amount: paymentIntent?.amount, //Add check here
            created: paymentIntent?.created, //Also check here
        })
```

Comment: I console logged the ```(paymentIntent)``` and it is ```"undefined"``` for some reason. And the ```error``` is returning the object with payment details, client ID, etc.